# Creating an interface for a JSON struct in golang

Tags: json, go

Say I have a `struct` that I bind `json` param data to like

```
type User struct {
  FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
}
```

The attribute `FirstName` has to be capitalized so that the `json` values can be binded to the struct.

But I also want to create an `interface` to accept any `struct` that has a `FirstName` like attribute.  Since `FirstName` is already capitalized and taken, I have to name the method something else.

```
type NameInterface interface {
    FirstName() string // nope
    FirstNameValue() string // maybe?
}
```

But it seems really weird to have to add a helper function for each attribute on all my `json` `struct`s just so they can work with an `interface`.  Is there something I'm misunderstanding or a programming pattern I'm missing?  What is the best way to get a `json` `struct` to work with `interfaces` in `go`?

More (what I am trying to do):

I want to parse `json` params that are coming from my `controllers` into `structs`.  And then pass that `struct` data into `filters` which then run `sql` commands to filter data based on the params data.  I wanted to use `interfaces` so I can pass in `structs` created from different sources into my `filters`.

Comment: Your "More" info sounds like your filters should work on interfaces while the JSON decoding happens completely on material structs which sounds reasonable and you do not need to JSON decode into interfaces. Maybe you should show real code as I cannot see any difficulty here: What is wrong implementing the methods your structs need to have to conform to an interface?

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces in Go specify *behaviour*, but you're trying to use them to describe *data*. This is why you're finding your approach to be difficult - and it's also why it's probably the wrong approach.

It's difficult to give a more specific answer without knowing what you're really trying to achieve, but if you, for example, want to be able to have functions that can read specific named fields from different struct types, you'll probably want to define one struct to describe this data and then embed that struct into other struct types.

Something like this might fit your needs:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
}

type User struct {
    Person
    // other User-specific fields
}

type Admin struct {
    Person
    // other Admin-specific fields
}

func Harass(p Person) { }

func main() {
    user := User{Person{"Frank"}}
    Harass(user.Person)
    admin := Admin{Person{"Angelina"}}
    Harass(admin.Person)
}
```

Comment: added more info to my question. Really appreciate your answer.